# How to call javascript function from html tag in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have one js file which has one function and one html file from which i am calling that js function. I have done something and its able to find the path of js file but its not able to find function inside that js file. Any help pelase its very important?
`index.html.erb`

```
<html>
 <html>
   <head>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "graph.js" %>
   </head>
   <body>
   <input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="Click Me!">
     <p>Hello!</p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

`graph.js`

```
 function popup()
        {
        alert("some text");
        }
```

Comment: Might be nothing but try putting a ; after `popup()` in your `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Any JS console errors?

Comment: `undefined popup() method`

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your javascript_include_tag..

it should be:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "graph" %>
```

Also.. ensure that graph.js is located in app/assets/javascripts

Comment: thank you for replying i also tried that and yes file is there.